# Ad units are being cut off in adsense responsive mode

Tags: html, css, debugging, adsense, ads

Before I began using responsive ads, I was able to specify a specific width and height for each ad unit before loading it via javascript and it would appear nicely, but the problem is, some pages scored me $0 RPM. I just switched over to responsive ad unit and I ended up making more than $0 RPM even though the entire ad does not appear on the screen. I'm looking for an answer.

Basically I made a skeleton code that is supposed to reserve the top of the screen solely for the advertisement. I want to be able to see the word "advertisement" in small letters (which I do), then the advertisement itself, then a space. Everything is fine except the advertisements themselves. I specified a max-height of 50px for the ad unit because I'm trying to make the advertisement size 50 pixels in height at most but I want the entire advertisement to appear on screen, not part of it.

What can I do to solve this issue? (and pardon me if the code below has insufficient content for advertising, but its just a skeleton code to play with. I'll deal with the text content later.)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #BOX{font-size:70%;width:100%;overflow:hidden;margin-bottom:8px}
      #AD{display:block;width:100%;overflow:hidden;max-height:50px}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ID="BOX">
      Advertisement<br>
      <script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" async>
      </script>
      <ins ID="AD">
      </ins>
      <script>

      if(Q('AD')){
        (adsbygoogle=window.adsbygoogle||[]).push(X())
      }

      function X(){
        Q('AD').className='adsbygoogle';
        return {
          params:{
            google_ad_client:'publisherID',
            google_ad_slot:'responsiveadunitslotID',
            google_ad_format:'auto',
            google_page_url:'http://www.example.com/'
            }
          }
      }

      function Q(x){
        return document.getElementById(x)
      }

      </script>
    </div>
    <p>Content</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to remove `google_ad_format:'auto'` (smart sizing) if you want [to control the height](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124) of `ins.adsbygoogle`. (Which means you'll need to set `height` on `#AD`, and you don't need `overflow:hidden`s.)